# Why was 'the tangible' used instead of 'tangibles'?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

Does ***the tangible*** have the same meaning as ***tangibles***? Why was ***the tangible*** used instead of ***tangibles***? Is it related to 'the + adjective = plural noun'? If so, the verb ***is*** doesn't make sense.

> Digital technology accelerates dematerialization by hastening the
>   migration from products to services. The liquid nature of services
>   means they don’t have to be bound to materials. But dematerialization
>   is not just about digital goods. The reason even solid physical
>   goods―like a soda can―can deliver more benefits while inhabiting less
>   material is because their heavy atoms are substituted by weightless
>   bits. ***The tangible is*** replaced by intangibles―intangibles like
>   better design, innovative processes, smart chips, and eventually
>   online connectivity―that do the work that more aluminum atoms used to
>   do. Soft things, like intelligence, are thus embedded into hard
>   things, like aluminum, that make hard things behave more like
>   software. Material goods infused with bits increasingly act as if they
>   were intangible services. Nouns morph to verbs. Hardware behaves like
>   software. In Silicon Valley they say it like this: “Software eats
>   everything.”

[The Inevitable: Understanding the 12 Technological Forces That Will Shape](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=SMe3CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=The+tangible+is+replaced+by+intangibles%E2%80%95intangibles+like+better+design,+innovative+processes,+smart+chips,+and+eventually+online+connectivity%E2%80%95that+do+the+work+that+more+aluminum+atoms+used+to+do.&source=bl&ots=fRFUy6-emo&sig=ACfU3U0f23UNSU-3mSgKG3IQRzHGxsXCKg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGyMK81MflAhWGP3AKHbLGDRMQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20tangible%20is%20replaced%20by%20intangibles%E2%80%95intangibles%20like%20better%20design%2C%20innovative%20processes%2C%20smart%20chips%2C%20and%20eventually%20online%20connectivity%E2%80%95that%20do%20the%20work%20that%20more%20aluminum%20atoms%20used%20to%20do.&f=false)

Comment: **The tangible** is a way of saying **That which is tangible**.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example sentence:

> In many retail transactions, the physical object has been replaced by a digital one.

Which object in which transaction am I referring to? No single object right? But "has" is still correct. The example you gave is similar. The singular here is used to speak in general.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the phrase "the tangible" refers to "tangibles" in the sentence.

The word "tangible"  here is a countable noun, meaning something that's real in a physical way. You can use the definite article "the" before a singular noun to refer in a general way to people or things of a particular type. For examples:

This book gives some useful tips for the beginner (= for beginners).

The cobra is a poisonous snake (=Cobras are poisonous snakes).  (Merriam Webster).

So it's all the same if you say "the tangible is" or "tangibles are". However, the latter seems more common.